# How to optimize insert of Hibernate object graphs with many @ManyToOne?

Tags: hibernate

I have lots of objects with lots of `@ManyToOne` relationships and I need to insert lots of them into the database.

My insert process has hit a bottleneck in this code, which ensures only a single instance of enum-like `@ManyToOne` entities are created and re-used:

```
public <U extends AutoEnum<?>> U saveIfAbsent(Session session, Class<U> clazz, U obj) {
    if (obj == null || obj.getValue() == null) {
        return null;
    }
    Optional<U> loadOptional = session.byNaturalId(clazz).using("value", obj.getValue()).loadOptional();
    if (loadOptional.isPresent()) {
        return loadOptional.get();
    } else {
        session.save(obj);
        return obj;
    }
}
```

The problem here is millions of round-trips to the database, which are just a few nanoseconds each, really add up to several hours of waiting for the process to finish.

So then I tried to cache the values using a `ConcurrentHashMap`:

```
private Map<String,Object> cache = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

public <U extends AutoEnum<?>> U saveIfAbsent(Session session, Class<U> clazz, U obj) {
    if (obj == null || obj.getValue() == null) {
        return null;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    U tmp = (U) cache.computeIfAbsent(clazz.getName() + ":" + obj.getValue(), key_ -> {
        Optional<U> loadOptional = session.byNaturalId(clazz).using("value", obj.getValue()).loadOptional();
        if (loadOptional.isPresent()) {
            return loadOptional.get();
        } else {
            session.save(obj);
            return obj;
        }
    });
    return tmp;
}
```

That unfortunately fails with:

```
...SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: insert or update on table "mytable" violates foreign key constraint
```

I believe what's happening there is that a "cached" object is returned which hasn't been committed to the database yet, as the thread that's doing the write loses the race to the thread that's re-using the object. *Doh*.

Is it possible to optimize this process so that a database round-trip is not incurred for every call to `saveIfAbsent()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to convert the child entities into stub objects that only contain the identifier, as asked in this question:

> [Inserting/Updating an entity with another referenced entities in Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38114918/inserting-updating-an-entity-with-another-referenced-entities-in-hibernate)

The relevant bits in my code now look like this:

```
    T autoEnumId = ... obtain ID value from cache ...
    ...
    U entity = clazz.newInstance();
    entity.setId(autoEnumId);
    parentEntity.setXXX(entity);
    ...
    session.save(parentEntity);
```